# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 700]

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm performing Linear Regression on the data provided by kaggle on Titanic Survivor prediction .Im trying to predict the list of survivors so iam keep getting this error even after i reshape the Y it still shows this error.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from csv import reader
import numpy as np

file = open('train.csv', "r")
lines = reader(file)
X = list(lines)
#Deleting unnecessary features
X=np.delete(X, (0), axis=0)
X=np.delete(X, (0), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (2), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (3), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (5), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (5), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (5), axis=1)
X=np.delete(X, (5), axis=1)
#Converting males to 1 and females to 0
for i in range(891):
   if X[i][2]== 'male':
       X[i][2]=1
   else:
       X[i][2]=0
Y=X.T[0]
#Converting strings to float
X1 = X.astype(np.float) 
Y1 = Y.astype(np.float)
Xw=X1.reshape(-1,1)
split = 700
train,test = Xw[:split,:],Xw[split:,:]
Ytrain,Ytest = Y1[:split],Y1[:split]
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(train.T, Ytrain)
logisticRegr.predict(test[0].T.reshape(1,-1))
score = logisticRegr.score(test.T, Ytest)
```

Comment: Have you tried only 'train' in place of 'train.T'?

Comment: Yea I've tried that too.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you to get familiar with [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) library for data handling, you can try the following:

```
# import
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

# convert to male/female, lets say the column is called as gender
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({'male': 0, 'female': 1})

trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(df, df['Survived'], train_size=700, stratify = df['Survived'],)

logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(trainX, trainY)

preds = logisticRegr.predict(testX)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(testY, preds)
```